# Does anyone know of source code for a web based study group?

Tags: c#, python

I'm looking for source code for a web based study group. I'd prefer something in Python or C#. I have searched google but I'm finding mostly existing study groups on particular topics and not software to host an online study group.

Can anyone help out?

---

Edit: Ah, I was unfamiliar with the buzzwords "Learning Management System" or "Virtual Learning Environment". Moodle is indeed the type of thing I was looking for, even if it is written in the horrible php "language".

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you mean by "host an online study group".

If it is about people collaborate to learn something, I think [moodle](http://moodle.org/) is what you are looking for.

Here is the [wikipedia lemma for moodle:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moodle)

> Moodle is a free and open source
>   e-learning software platform, also
>   known as a Course Management System,
>   Learning Management System, or Virtual
>   Learning Environment. It has a
>   significant user base with 49,256
>   registered sites with 28,177,443 users
>   in 2,571,855 courses (as of February,
>   2009).

Here is how the [moodle people](http://moodle.org/) describe it themselves:

> Moodle is an Open Source Course
>   Management System (CMS), also known as
>   a Learning Management System (LMS) or
>   a Virtual Learning Environment (VLE).
>   It has become very popular among
>   educators around the world as a tool
>   for creating online dynamic web sites
>   for their students.

It is not written in Python or C#, but PHP and released under GPL.
You can install it on your webserver or use free moodle hosting like [e-socrates](http://www.e-socrates.org/).

Comment: +1 for moodle.  Moodle seems to have most of the features of Blackboard and WebCT (which is owned by Blackboard).  Blackboard or WebCT seem to be used by all the local colleges for online course work.  If you want software to host a study group, then reinventing the wheel does not make sense.  If you want to build and understand your own online study group software, then I would start with Turbogears or Django and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be work on a django based course MS - http://peach3.nl/trac . However, the source is not available yet :(

I am interested in developping such an app (free open-source) in django (which I am learning), so if anybody else wants to help email me (a web designer would help a lot).

Rado